# Prepositions of nouns

Tags: preposition

I have been searching for a book or a website that specializes in prepositions of nouns. For example:

> der Kontakt **zu** jdm.
>   der Genuss **von** etw.

In many cases, there is no rule to what preposition should one use with specific nouns so please if you can provide me with a good book I would be grateful.

Comment: "der Kontakt mit" is also correct as well as "der Kontakt zwischen (Eltern und Kindern)". The preposition mostly depends on what you want to say and not on a noun.

Comment: @Eller Excellent. Where can I find these utilities of prepositions?

Answer (score 2):

Googling ["Nomen mit Präpositionen"](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22Nomen+mit+Pr%C3%A4positionen%22) or ["Substantive mit Präpositionen"](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22Substantive+mit+Pr%C3%A4positionen%22) may yield some results, for instance this [list by PONS](https://de.pons.com/daten/pdf/Praxis-Grammatik/02_Substantive_mit_Praepositionen.pdf).

There is indeed a book on the topic: Wolfgang Müller, *Wörterbuch deutscher Präpositionen*, [De Gruyter](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110256093/html), 2012. With a price of 510 €, the book is clearly not aimed at language learners. You might gain access via a library.

Some remarks.

1. *Von* is always possible if it substitutes for a genitive, such as in your example.

> der Genuss dies**er** Drogen *(definite)*
> der Genuss **von** Drogen *(indefinite)*

2. Prepositions have multiple meanings. This carries over to combinations of nouns with prepositions. Having a sound knowledge of the basic meanings of prepositions should allow you to derive the appropriate meaning of the combination in many, if not most, circumstances.

> eine Mitteilung **über** das Webformular *(characterising the medium: "via")*
> eine Mitteilung **über** das weitere Vorgehen *(characterising the message: "about")*

3. However, there are some idiosyncratic combinations of verbs, nouns, and adjectives with prepositions that have to be learned. You should be able to pick these up just by reading and listening to a lot of German. This would seem like a more realistic strategy than rote memorisation.

4. Most of the lists found on the Internet show a lack of reflection. For instance, in the list by PONS linked above: *Ärger über* can be derived from *sich ärgern über*. *Armut an (roten Blutkörperchen)* has a meaning of *an* that occurs independent of *Armut* and seems to specify a collection of something.

> jung **an** Jahren, reich **an** Erfahrungen; arm **an** Freuden ([WDG](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/an))
> Was wir **an** Erfahrungen gesammelt haben, kann uns niemand mehr nehmen.